# Condicional if == en C++ no me funcional

Tags: c++

Estoy intentando hacer una comparacion entre los datos que tengo en una estructura y lo que estoy ingresando por teclado, pero no funciona.

```
 for (y=0;y<=x;y++)
  {

    if (aDoc[y].especialidad == esp)

    {
      printf("%d \t %s \t \t%s \t \t %d ", aDoc[y].id, aDoc[y].nombre,aDoc[y].especialidad, aDoc[y].cant);
     

    }
    
    else{
        system("CLS");
         gotoxy(20,5); printf("No se encontraron coincidencias");
    }

 }
```

---

Nos se que estoy haciendo mal. Lo que se busca es que el usuario pueda saber cuales son los doctores que pertencen a una determinada especialidad.

---

Este es el codigo completo:

````
#include <conio.h>

#include <string.h>

#include <windows.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <iostream>

#include <string>



#define L 4

#define t1 "Clinica Buena Salud"

#define t2 "La Vega, Rep.Dom"

#define t3 "Estructura de Datos"

#define t4 "Registro de Medicos"

#define t5 "M e n u   P r i n c i p a l"



#define BLACK         0x00

#define BLUE          0x01

#define GREEN         0x02

#define CYAN          0x03

#define RED           0x04

#define MAGENTA       0x05

#define BROWN         0x06

#define LIGHTGRAY     0x07

#define DARKGRAY      0x08

#define LIGHTBLUE     0x09

#define LIGHTGREEN    0x0A

#define LIGHTCYAN     0x0B

#define LIGHTRED      0x0C

#define LIGHTMAGENTA  0x0D

#define YELLOW        0x0E

#define WHITE         0x0F



void setcolor( unsigned short color )

{

    HANDLE hCon = GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE );

    SetConsoleTextAttribute( hCon, color );

}



void gotoxy( short x, short y )

{

    HANDLE hConsoleOutput;

    COORD Cursor_an_Pos = { x, y };

    hConsoleOutput = GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE );

    SetConsoleCursorPosition( hConsoleOutput, Cursor_an_Pos );

}



struct Doc

 {

   int id, cant;

   char nombre[60], especialidad[3];

   

 } vDoc, aDoc[L];


struct Esp
{
    char nombre[3];
} aEsp;

int x;



void llenar()

{

  int s=1;

   do{

     system("CLS");

     gotoxy(20,8);printf("ID........: "); scanf("%d",&aDoc[x].id);

     gotoxy(20,9);printf("Nombre....: "); scanf("%s",&aDoc[x].nombre);

     gotoxy(20,10);printf("Especialidad...: "); scanf("%s",&aDoc[x].especialidad);

     gotoxy(20,11);printf("Cantidad de Pacientes......: "); scanf("%i",&aDoc[x].cant);

     gotoxy(20,13);printf("Presione 0 para salir | otra tecla continua");scanf("%d",&s);
     
    

     if (s==0)

        break;

     x++;

   }while ( (x<=L) || (s==0) );

}



void ordenar() //metodo de burbujas

 {

    int i,j;

    //metodo burbuja

    for (i=0; i<=x-1; i++)

    for (j=i+1; j<=x; j++)

    {

       if (aDoc[i].id > aDoc[j].id)

       {

        vDoc = aDoc[i];

        aDoc[i] = aDoc[j];

        aDoc[j] = vDoc;

       }

    }

}



void mostrar()

{

  int y;

  system("CLS");

  printf(" ID |  Nombre      | Especialidad | Cant. Pacientes \n");

  printf("====================================\n");

  for (y=0;y<=x;y++)

    {

      printf("%d \t %s \t \t%s \t \t %i \n", aDoc[y].id, aDoc[y].nombre,aDoc[y].especialidad, aDoc[y].cant);

    }

  getch();

}



void mostrarxcarrera()

{

  int y;

  string esp[3];

  system("CLS");

  gotoxy(20,5); printf("Especialidad a mostrar: "); scanf("%s",&esp);
;


  gotoxy(1,6);
  

  printf(" ID |  Nombre      | Especialidad | Cant Pacientes \n");

  printf("====================================\n");

  for (y=0;y<=x;y++)
  {

    if (aDoc[y].especialidad == esp)

    {
      printf("%d \t %s \t \t%s \t \t %d ", aDoc[y].id, aDoc[y].nombre,aDoc[y].especialidad, aDoc[y].cant);
     

    }
    
    else{
        system("CLS");
         gotoxy(20,5); printf("No se encontraron coincidencias");
    }

 }


 getch();

}



void cuadro(int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2)

{

  int x,y;

  for (x=x1;x<=x2;x++)

    {

      gotoxy(x,y1); printf("%c",205);

      gotoxy(x,y2); printf("%c",205);

    }

  for (y=y1;y<=y2;y++)

    {

      gotoxy(x1,y); printf("%c",186);

      gotoxy(x2,y); printf("%c",186);

    }

      gotoxy(x1,y1); printf("%c",201);

      gotoxy(x2,y1); printf("%c",187);

      gotoxy(x1,y2); printf("%c",200);

      gotoxy(x2,y2); printf("%c",188);

}



int main()

{

  x=0;

  int op=1;

  do{

    system("CLS");

    setcolor(DARKGRAY);

    cuadro(1,78,1,6);

    setcolor(BLUE);

    gotoxy( (80-strlen(t1))/2, 2);printf(t1);

    gotoxy( (80-strlen(t2))/2, 3);printf(t2);

    gotoxy( (80-strlen(t3))/2, 4);printf(t3);

    gotoxy( (80-strlen(t4))/2, 5);printf(t4);

    setcolor(WHITE);

    cuadro(10,70,7,20);

    gotoxy( (80-strlen(t5))/2, 8);printf(t5);

    gotoxy(20,10); printf("1- Registrar Doctor");

    gotoxy(20,11); printf("2- Ordenar");

    gotoxy(20,12); printf("3- Mostrar Todo");

    gotoxy(20,13); printf("4- Mostrar por Especialidad");

    gotoxy(20,14); printf("0- Salir");

    gotoxy(20,16); printf("Su opcion: ");scanf("%d",&op);

    switch(op)

      {

    case(1):llenar(); break;

    case(2):ordenar(); break;

    case(3):mostrar(); break;

    case(4): mostrarxcarrera(); break;

    case(0): break;

      }

  }while (op!=0);

  system("CLS");

  return 0;

}```
````

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Si esp es un array, que esperas que haga aca? aDoc[y].especialidad == esp

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para comparar cadenas de caracteres tienes que usar `strcmp`:

```
if (strcmp(aDoc[y].especialidad, esp) == 0)
{
    // Son iguales
}
else
{
    // No son iguales
}
```

Lo que hace en este caso el operador de comparación es comparar las direcciones de memoria de los arrays. Como cada array está en una dirección de memoria diferente, el resultado será siempre falso

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, esta era la solución que necesitaba. Me has ayudado muchísimo. Un fuerte abrazo.